# 20.04 autoinstall ejecting iso after first reboot

Tags: 20.04, cloud-init, subiquity

I am working on upgrading an offline/disconnected installation of Ubuntu that used to be 18.04 with D-I to 20.04 with autoinstall/cloud-init.

I have most everything working out so far, but one of the changes I cannot find documentation for is hurting my unattended install.  Basically when cloud-init is finished with the first cloud-config stage before it reboots into the installed 20.04 system, it ejects the media (in my case ejecting the virtual drive in a VM).

Debian-Installer had a catch for this with `d-i cdrom-detect/eject boolean false` but I cannot find a similar setting for my cloud-config file.

Hoping this exists, or if not is there a workaround?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stop the physical ejection, then I think you'd have to patch the `/sbin/casper-stop` script in the installation environmment.  If you simply want to avoid the prompt to "Please remove the installation medium, then press ENTER" then you can create the file `/run/casper-no-prompt`.  Either of these options could be done in `early-commands` of your `autoinstall` config.

`autoinstall` config like the following might work

```
early-commands:
    - sed -ie 's/eject -p/#eject -p/' /sbin/casper-stop
    - touch /run/casper-no-prompt
```

When the installer, *subiquity*, finishes and reboots, it simply runs `/sbin/reboot`.  This can be seen [in the subiquity source code](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/a76581cd2b973b55e55c6ac05b5bf47168493140/subiquity/server/controllers/reboot.py#L81).

The installer environment will run `/sbin/casper-stop` during shutdown because of the systemd service defined in `/lib/systemd/system/casper.service`.  This script will display the prompt and eject the media.  The [source code of the script](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/tree/bin/casper-stop#n73) shows that the prompt is configurable, but the `eject` command is called as long as the cdrom is mounted, and advertised as removable.

See also

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528577/how-to-skip-please-remove-the-installation-medium-then-press-enter